# Database Security - Prevent column writing?

Tags: postgresql

I am using a Postgres db. I am concerned if someone gets in my DB, they could change the price of my products to $0 and download my products.

Am I able to prevent writing / editing of that column except by a specific user?

I'm in a rails app, if it matters.

Comment: postgresql supports column level security. see the GRANT statement in the docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am concerned if someone gets in my DB

Well, don't let them.

> Am I able to prevent writing / editing of that column except by a specific user?

If your tables aren't owned by the user the application runs as, then yes, you can use column-level `GRANT`s to give partial access to tables.

So you'd `GRANT` everyone the right to use the other columns, and only grant one particular database user the right to edit that particular column.

However:

- This only works with database users created with `CREATE USER` or `CREATE ROLE`. If your application does its own user management with ordinary database tables, PostgreSQL's permissions cannot be used.
- Rails likes to have the application user own the tables so it can do migrations etc. You cannot restrict the rights of the owner.

... so in practice, I suspect that the answer will be "no, not with Rails, do it at the application level".

There's not really enough detail here to say more.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I guess I am trying to limit what a user could get access to if the system was compromised in addition to trying to prevent the system from being compromised in the first place. So if my web server was compromised, the db may still have some level of security.

Comment: @Jeff Sensible goal, but AFAIK very hard to achieve with Rails. You'd need a way to tell Rails to run as a normal user that didn't own the tables/databases, and to prompt you for admin credentials when it detected that a migration needed to be run. There might be addons/extensions to make this possible. I don't really do Rails. Maybe ask a Rails-specific question about running Rails with reduced database privileges and doing migrations with a separate user ID?